# Power BI service refreshing fine but desktop version fails

Tags: powerbi, refresh, powerbi-desktop

I've recently came across an issue where my schedules refresh on the service is working fine but when I try to refresh via the desktop version it just fails.

Its stuck on "waiting for" sharepoint site and then eventually throws an error like below. There is no query that refers to "construction potential position" table. It's an old table that was removed almost a year ago + I've managed to refresh the desktop version last month with no issues. I also checked the privacy settings but all seems to be set up correctly.

Any thoughts? Thanks!